# Jquery live click problem

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.3.2 library. and (jquery 1.8.7 js and css)

Now,

```
$("div > ul[id=color] > li ").live("mouseover", function() {    
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

is working but,

```
$("div > ul[id=color] > li ").live("click", function() { 
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

is not working. Please tell what can be the possible reason?.. Thanks

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/2Mkjk/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that a descendant or anscestor element has an `onclick` handler that returns `false` or calls `event.stopPropagation()`. Since `.live()` relies on the event travelling all the way up to the document level, if the event is blocked anywhere along the element tree then your handler won't be called.

---

*Sidenote*: IDs are unique, and [jQuery has a shortcut for them](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), therefore your selector can be simplified to:

```
"#color > li"
```

Comment: Actually another click event was attached to it that was returning false.

Comment: @001priyank: Don't forget to "Accept" a helpful answer by clicking the large checkbox to the left of it.